# How can I list all cronjobs created by puppet?

Tags: puppet, cron

I have several crontabs defined in a pp file, e.g:

```
cron { 'puppet-cron1':
    ensure  => present,
    command => "cat /etc/issue",
    user    => root,
    minute  => '*/30',
}
cron { 'puppet-cron2':
    ensure  => present,
    command => "cat /etc/issue",
    user    => www-data,
    minute  => '*/30',
}
```

How do I list all cronjobs created by puppet on a system?

I tried `puppet ressource cron`, which lists only the root cronjob:

```
cron { 'puppet-cron1':
  ensure  => 'present',
  command => 'cat /etc/issue',
  minute  => ['*/30'],
  target  => 'root',
  user    => 'root',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`puppet resource`](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.5/reference/man/resource.html) command on the system in question, like this:

```
# puppet resource cron
```

This should show you all `cron` resources Puppet manages on that system.

Comment: This is the result of the command.

`cron { 'puppet-cron1': ensure  => 'present', command => 'cat /etc/issue', minute  => ['*/30'], target  => 'root', user    => 'root', }`

It only shows the root cronjob, not the one for www-data. I have verified that the www-data cronjob does indeed exist.

Comment: Indeed, running `puppet resource cron` as root only shows the Puppet-managed cronjobs for the user `root`. You can run `sudo -u www-data puppet resource cron` to see the Puppet-managed cronjobs for the `www-data` user. Not sure if there is a way to list all Puppet resources for all users without doing some shell scripting.